# Eclipse, Pydev and getting Non-ASCII (Chinese) characters to work

Tags: eclipse, encoding

To start my region is set to China, I'm using a Chinese version of Windows7, and I have the character set installed.

I want to get Chinese characters to work:
print ("我“） for example.

and get rid of this error: "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character"

In Eclipse I have set UTF-8 in:
Project->Preferences->Resource
Run Config->Common->Encoding
Edit->Set Encoding
File->Properties_>Text-Encoding

I have tried putting: # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- at the top of my file (utf-8 as well). 
When I do the following at the start of the file it still doesn't work: 
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
 
When I run the above at the prompt it works just fine, but it won't in Eclipse.

This is because it becomes inaccessible, so I tried putting it in sitecustomize and then I get 'import sitecustomize' failed. I tried it in Python27 and 33.

I would like to get this to work in Eclipse so I can continue on my project. I am a fairly experienced programmer, though been out of it for awhile. I've only been using Eclipse and Python for less than a week.